# Scheme zip function with possible uneven lists

Tags: list, function, zip, scheme

I know this question has been asked before, and my solution is the same as many of the answers but I have a special test case that won't work correctly with the common solution to this problem.

The solution that I have found for the zip problem like many others is

```
(define (zip l1 l2)(map list l1 l2))
```

. . .which works great with given arguments such as

```
(zip '(a b c) '(1 2 3)) => ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
```

but I also want the zip function to work for cases where my arguments do not match length like

```
(zip '(a b c) '(1)) => ((a 1) (b ()) (c ()))
```

I have not found a solution to this problem and not really sure how to approach it where each list can be any length.

Comment: What you want to do is not clear. Your desired result is not properly typed: the first list consists of a symbol and an integer, the second two lists consist of a symbol and a list. That's possible, but unlikely. A better formulation of (zip '(a b c) '(1)) would return ((a 1)) and drop the excess items or, alternately, return ((a 1) (b) (c)). And what would you do when the zip function is given three or more lists? Please clarify exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I want to have a mapping between two lists, if the lists are even then each item is mapped to the same index of the item in the other list such as (zip '(a b c) '(1 2 3)) => ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)). The additional result that I want, but cannot produce is in the case when the two lists given as parameters are not the same length, so the result that I DO want is (zip '(a b c) '(1)) => ((a 1) (b ()) (c ())) where if there is not an item for the first list to map to in the second list, it just pairs with an empty list, but with the current function definition will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a simple iterative version that works for 2 lists only:

```
(define (zip lst1 lst2 (placeholder '()))

  (define (my-car lst)
    (if (empty? lst) placeholder (car lst)))
  (define (my-cdr lst)
    (if (empty? lst) lst (cdr lst)))

  (let loop ((lst1 lst1) (lst2 lst2) (res '()))
    (if (and (empty? lst1) (empty? lst2))
        (reverse res)
        (loop (my-cdr lst1) (my-cdr lst2) 
              (cons (list (my-car lst1) (my-car lst2)) res)))))
```

such as

```
(zip '(a b c) '(1 2 3))
=> '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))

(zip '(a b c) '(1))
=> '((a 1) (b ()) (c ()))
```

From this, you can generalise to n lists, but to avoid keyword parameters you have to put the placeholder parameter first:

```
(define (zip placeholder . lsts)

  (define (my-car lst)
    (if (empty? lst) placeholder (car lst)))
  (define (my-cdr lst)
    (if (empty? lst) lst (cdr lst)))

  (let loop ((lsts lsts) (res '()))
    (if (andmap empty? lsts)
        (reverse res)
        (loop (map my-cdr lsts) 
              (cons (apply list (map my-car lsts)) res)))))
```

such as

```
(zip '() '(a b c) '(1 2 3))
==> '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))

(zip '() '(a b c) '(1))
==> '((a 1) (b ()) (c ()))

(zip '() '(a b c) '(1) '(x y))
=> '((a 1 x) (b () y) (c () ()))
```

I believe that **andmap** is the only Racket-specific function here, which probably has some Scheme or SRFI equivalent depending on your implementation.

**EDIT**

Since the solution is based on creating lists of equal length, instead of duplicating the zip algorithm, you can also first add the placeholders to the lists before doing the classic map-list stuff:

```
(define (zip placeholder . lsts)
  (let* ((max-len (apply max (map length lsts))) ; the length of the longest lists
         (equal-length-lists                     ; adjusts all lists to the same length,
          (map                                   ;   filling with placeholder
           (lambda (lst) (append lst (make-list (- max-len (length lst)) placeholder)))
           lsts)))
    (apply map list equal-length-lists)))        ; classical zip
```

Comment: I tested the first solution and it works great, but could you explain the function definition a little more with how you have the placeholder part? I'm a bit confused why its structured the way it is. Sorry still new to scheme.

Comment: The placeholder is an optional parameter to the zip procedure; if you don't give any other placeholder then '() will be used, as in your example. Now, since in your case some lists will end up empty during the loop whereas others still have elements, I have defined my own car and cdr procedures which, instead of choking on an empty list, will just return the placeholder or '() instead. So I kind of align the length of the shorter lists to the length of the longest list. The main loop is a classic zip function, unaware of the placeholder stuff, which will end only when all lists are processed

Comment: Thank you so much, that make a lot of sense now.

Comment: Added an even shorter solution based on the classic map-list.

Answer (score 0):

It's not semantically correct to have `(zip '(a b c) '(1))` => `((a 1) (b ()) (c ()))` (unless you're specifically using `()` as a placeholder value); it's more sensible to have `((a 1) (b) (c))`. Here's an implementation that achieves that:

```
(define (zip-with-uneven . lists)
  (define (advance lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        lst
        (cdr lst)))
  (define (firsts lists)
    (let loop ((lists lists)
               (result '()))
      (cond ((null? lists) (reverse result))
            ((null? (car lists)) (loop (cdr lists) result))
            (else (loop (cdr lists) (cons (caar lists) result))))))

  (let loop ((lists lists)
             (results '()))
    (if (andmap null? lists)
        (reverse results)
        (loop (map advance lists)
              (cons (firsts lists) results)))))
```

`andmap` is from Racket. If you're not using Racket, you can use `every` from SRFI 1 instead.

---

If you *really* want to use a placeholder, here's a (Racket-specific) version that supports placeholders. The default placeholder is `(void)`, which I presume is never a valid value you'd want to put in your result list.

```
(define (zip-with-uneven #:placeholder (ph (void)) . lists)
  (define (advance lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        lst
        (cdr lst)))
  (define (cons-with-placeholder a d)
    (if (void? a)
        d
        (cons a d)))
  (define (firsts lists)
    (let loop ((lists lists)
               (result '()))
      (cond ((null? lists) (reverse result))
            ((null? (car lists))
             (loop (cdr lists) (cons-with-placeholder ph result)))
            (else (loop (cdr lists) (cons (caar lists) result))))))

  (let loop ((lists lists)
             (results '()))
    (if (andmap null? lists)
        (reverse results)
        (loop (map advance lists)
              (cons (firsts lists) results)))))
```