# Creating a list of pairs from two lists of different sizes

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme, racket

Still new to Scheme, and I'm currently having trouble with the creation of a list of pairs constructed from two separate lists of different lengths.

Here is my current code:

```
#lang racket
    
(define letters '(a b c))

(define (create-lst-letters lst)
  (map (lambda (x y) (list x y)) letters lst))
```

Console input:

```
(create-lst-letters '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
```

Current output:

```
map: all lists must have same size
     first list length: 8
     other list length: 3
```

Wanted output:

```
'((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3) (a . 4) (b . 5) (c . 6) (a . 7) (b . 8))
```

Another intuition would be to get the quotient and remainder of the length of the input list divided by "letters". Make a new list by appending "letters" quotient times, and then concatenating the first remainder number of elements of "letters". With that new list perform a map as above. I don't feel this is good practice nor an elegant solution, but I'm out of other ideas.

Comment: Some prior art on a similar question: [Scheme zip function with possible uneven lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256963/scheme-zip-function-with-possible-uneven-lists).

Comment: If you want to create a pair, use `cons`, not `list`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`in-cycle`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=in-cycle#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-cycle%29%29) and [`for/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=in-cycle#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29) to concisely produce the output that you want.

```
#lang racket
    
(define letters '(a b c))

(define (create-lst-letters lst)
  (for/list ([x (in-cycle letters)] [y lst])
    (cons x y)))

(create-lst-letters '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
; '((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3) (a . 4) (b . 5) (c . 6) (a . 7) (b . 8))
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how to reconcile this with the documentation for `for/list`. As you use it, `for/list` zips together its sequences - fair enough. But all the examples in the documentation appear to instead take the cartesian product of its sequences. What am I missing?

Comment: There's `for*/list` which does cartesian product, and there's `for/list` which does parallel iteration (it's possible to add a `#:when` clause to turn parallel iteration to cartesian product, but that's not what's happening in my code).

Answer (score 0):

A pure Scheme version:

```
#!r7rs

(import (scheme base)
        (scheme list))

(define create-lst-letters
  (let ((letters (circular-list 'a 'b 'c)))
    (lambda (lst)
      (map cons letters lst))))

(create-lst-letters '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
; ==> ((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3) (a . 4) (b . 5) (c . 6) (a . 7) (b . 8))
```

I use Racket and it doesn't have a Red edition of R7RS yet, but thsi can easily be rewritten to R6RS using SRFI-1 (same as (scheme list))

```
#!r6rs

(import (except (rnrs base) map)
        (only (srfi :1) map circular-list))

(define create-lst-letters
  (let ((letters (circular-list 'a 'b 'c)))
    (lambda (lst)
      (map cons letters lst))))

(create-lst-letters '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
; ==> ((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3) (a . 4) (b . 5) (c . 6) (a . 7) (b . 8))
```

And of course if you don't like writing Scheme code you can write almost the same using `#lang racket` language.

```
#lang racket

(require srfi/1)

(define create-lst-letters
  (let ((letters (circular-list 'a 'b 'c)))
    (lambda (lst)
      (map cons letters lst))))

(create-lst-letters '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
; ==> ((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3) (a . 4) (b . 5) (c . 6) (a . 7) (b . 8))
```